# Trim multiple clips with one command of FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php, pyffmpeg

1. I have a video called 1.mp4
2. I want to extract 17+17= 34 total clips from this video **with one FFmpeg command**
3. Each clip should have a unique name like 1a 1b 1c 1d and so on.
4. 17 clips will have a 1920x1080 dimension
   and remaining 17 will have 720x720 dimension
5. I will appreciate if someone can help me to do this. It will save my several hours.

Comment: Will your inputs always be the same size, or will they be arbitrary? Do you need the audio? Should the video be cropped or padded to fit 1920x1080 and 720x720?

Comment: 1. Every morning I get video in 1920 x 1080 dimension
2. This dimension suits to my client's youtube channel hence I just have to trim it with given timestamps
3. The same video has to go on twitter with different dimension (700x700) i.e. 1:1 ratio
4. Same video has to go on instagram with different dimension (1080x1920)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Adapt this shortened example for 2+2 outputs:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex
"[0:v]trim=start=0:end=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[va1][vb1];
 [0:v]trim=start=5:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[va2][vb2];
 [0:a]atrim=start=0:end=3,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,asplit[aa1][ab1];
 [0:a]atrim=start=5:end=10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,asplit[aa2][ab2];
 [va1]scale=700:700:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=700:700[700_1];
 [va2]scale=700:700:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=700:700[700_2];
 [vb1]scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:1920[1920_1];
 [vb2]scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:1920[1920_2]"
-map "[700_1]"  -map "[aa1]" 1a.mp4
-map "[700_2]"  -map "[aa2]" 1b.mp4
-map "[1920_1]" -map "[ab1]" 2a.mp4
-map "[1920_2]" -map "[ab2]" 2b.mp4
```

- Command was split into multiple lines so you can read it easier. Make it one long line before executing.
- See [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit specific size](https://superuser.com/q/547296/) for other options if you don't like the crop-to-fit.
- The filter labels, such as `[va1]`, are arbitrary and you can use whatever label names you prefer.

These [filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) are used:

- (a)trim - to trim the video/audio
- (a)setpts - to reset timestamps
- (a)split - to make copies of the trimmed stream for the two different output sizes so you only have to trim once per clip
- scale - to scale the video
- crop - to crop the video

Comment: I am amazed with this reply. This is the first time I have used stack exchange and I think I got what I want. I am from creative background and have no experience of coding. I will be really thankful of you, if you could help me to design this command in such a way I can supply inputs in HH:MM:FF (Hour:Minutes:Frames) format,

Comment: One more request please give command in one line (without breaking / pressing enter button) when I copy that command in notepad it doesn't come the way as it should.

Comment: Is it possible to apply the same scaling and cropping settings to all segments without repeating this for each segment, or even for each output video? For example I want to do a cut-and-merge similar to above for multiple segments, and my original command has: -filter:v "scale='min(480,iw)':-2:flags=lanczos,fps=15" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22